# Will a Cloud Function finish if HTTP request is cancelled?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a Python 3.7 Cloud Function that is triggered via HTTP request.

Function execution can take up to several seconds (2-5).

In some cases, the HTTP request is sent using Javascript from the website's front end.

My questions is, will the Cloud Function finish it's execution normally even if the browser window (that triggered the HTTP request using JS) is closed or user navigates to another page. The function returns "ok" but in that case it doesn't have a destination where to return it.

Comment: Yes the function finish, because it's triggered by the first page, and return code to a destination that doesn't exists. But the question is why the frontend trigger the cloud function and doesn't wait the result?

Comment: One use case is analytics. Collecting data about clicks and other user actions. For example: JS triggers HTTP requests that triggers a Cloud Function that triggers a Pub/Sub topic that triggers another Cloud Function that writes data into the database.

Comment: Ok, so is something like: ehi cloud function, write this information to this DB. Your first cloud function can return a simple 200, and if there is an error log something to stackdriver. I think you can't consider the cloud function response.

Comment: Yeah, all I really need to know is that the cloud function finishes normally even if the browser window is closed before the HTTP request finished or returns something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function code doesn't do anything differently based on what happens to the client after the request is sent.  In fact, it is not even possible to try to cancel the function's execution after the request has been sent.

Closing the connection doesn't affect the outcome from the function's point of view.  If a client closes the connection before the response is received, it will just not receive any response generated by the function, so you can not be certain if the client acted on any information returned by the function.